# Ms Bot Framework how to handle the end of conversation event?

Tags: botframework

I am new to bot framework, and I am using node.js. I want to handle the "endOfConversation" through event and handle the result like below.

`bot.on('endOfConversation', function(result){
    console.log(result);
    // handle the result object here. Potentially make a callout to other third party services.
  });`

However, When I end a conversation using 'session.endConversation()' the event is not trigger. I wonder, if this is a bug in botframework? or it is because I am not wiring it up correctly?

please help!

Answer (score 0):

`endConversation` both clears the current dialog stack and resets all data stored in the session, except userData, and sends a message to the user. But it doesn't need you to specify a callback, it just sends a message.

Maybe you should check `endConversationAction`

```
bot.dialog('Something', [
    // do sth
])
.endConversationAction('CancelSomething', 'Operation cancelled', {
    matches: /^cancel$/,
    confirmPrompt: `Are you sure you wish to cancel?`
})
```